# How to specify axis limits in geoviews (python)?

Tags: python, bokeh, geopandas, geoviews

I have been using geopandas, but I am trying to switch to geoviews because it is more interactive. I'm wondering how to specify the axis limits for plotted data as a default view. I understand that it will always plot all of the data that exist, but it would be nice to have a given zoom for the purpose of this project. I posted the image of the map output below. However, I want it to output with xlim = ([-127, -102]) and ylim = ([25, 44]). I looked on stackoverflow and other places online and was unable to find the answer.

```
# Read in shapefiles
fire = pd.read_pickle(r'fire_Aug2020.pkl')
fire = fire.loc[fire['FRP'] != -999.0, :]

# Assign gv.Image
data = gv.Dataset(fire[['Lon','Lat','YearDay']]) 
points = data.to(gv.Points, ['Lon','Lat'])
m = (points).opts(tools = ['hover'], width = 400, height = 200)
m
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are very close to a working solution. Try to add `xlim` and `ylim` as tuple to the `opts` call.

**Minimal Example**

Comment: GeoViews is based on Holoviews, see the [documentation](https://github.com/holoviz/geoviews#what-is-it) for more details.

Because GeoViews is not installed on my machine, the example below uses HoloViews. I will update this answer soon.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts

hv.extension('bokeh')

fire = pd.DataFrame({'Lat':np.random.randint(10,80,50),'Lon':np.random.randint(-160,-60,50)})

data = hv.Dataset(fire[['Lon','Lat']])
points = data.to(hv.Points, ['Lon','Lat'])
(points).opts(tools = ['hover'], width = 400)
```

Above is the output without limits and below I make use of `xlim` and `ylim`.

[image: Without limits]

```
(points).opts(tools = ['hover'], width = 400, height = 200, xlim=(-127,-102), ylim=(25,44))
```

[image: Using some limits]

Comment: I am not able to install GEoViews right now and hope the answer solves the problem anyway.